# torch geometric error: FileNotFound: Could not find module '...\.conda\envs\...\Lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\_convert_cuda.pyd'

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, pytorch-geometric

torch geometric error

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module '...\.conda\envs\urop\Lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\_convert_cuda.pyd' Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Versions:

torch_geometric==2.0.4

```
pytorch                   1.11.0              py3.8_cpu_0    pytorch
pytorch-cluster           1.6.0           py38_torch_1.11.0_cu113    pyg
pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
pytorch-scatter           2.0.9           py38_torch_1.11.0_cu113    pyg
pytorch-sparse            0.6.14          py38_torch_1.11.0_cu113    pyg
pytorch-spline-conv       1.2.1           py38_torch_1.11.0_cu113    pyg
torchvision               0.12.0                 py38_cpu    pytorch
```

Comment: Does this [link](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/1994#:~:text=hello%20I%20solve%20this%20question) solve your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved** my problem with this error. I simply had an *old version of Torch* and installed torch-scatter and torch-sparse pointing to a wheel with a newer PyTorch version with the -f pip flag (pip install -v torch-scatter -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.12.1+cu116.html).

Creating a new environment, installing the newest PyTorch version, and pointing to the correct wheel worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the web for the answer to this question, as I had installed pytorch geometric through a new environment in conda immediately (the cpu only version), thinking that it would install all of the correct dependencies. That did not work and I ended up with the error shown from the question above.

I then tried to install the cuda version. I installed cuda 11.6 (I am on windows so this was the only one the works with the stable versions). I then tried to installed pytorch and pytorch geometric separately by following the documentation on each of their sites, installing the proper versions of the software to no avail.

I was able to solve it as of today by doing the following:

1. Create a new environment in conda
2. Install the CPU only version of pytorch using the following:

> ```
> conda install pytorch==1.12.1 torchvision==0.13.1 torchaudio==0.12.1 cpuonly -c pytorch
> ```

3. Install pytorch geometric using the code from their documentation:

> ```
> conda install pyg -c pyg
> ```

This seemed to have worked